# How can I pass my config parameters to the frontend via Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

I have a question. I have created 2 config files. I can already use the parameters in the application.properties. My goal is to be able to display and edit the parameters later in the frontend. Like normal settings of any application. Unfortunately, I do not have an exact idea how I can implement this.

Does anyone have an idea for me how I can send my config via RestApi to the frontend?

My application.properties

```
#ConfigMaintenance
config.maintenance.next-Available-Update-Version=1.28.5
config.maintenance.next-Available-Update-Date= 18.05.2022
config.maintenance.automatic-update= true
config.maintenance.update-Api-Token= sk021=!2jsn?=jacmw
config.maintenance.latest-Version= 1.28.4

#ConfigGeneral
config.general.volume=56
config.general.dark-Mode=false
config.general.night-Mode=false
config.general.fps=144
config.general.screen-Resolution=1920 x 1080
```

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import lombok.Data;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.general")
@Data
public class ConfigGeneral {
    private int volume;
    private Boolean nightModus;
    private Boolean darkMode;
    private int fps;
    private String screenResolution;

}
```

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import lombok.Data;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.maintenance")
@Data
public class ConfigMaintenance {
    private String nextAvailableUpdateVersion;
    private String nextAvailableUpdateDate;
    private Boolean automaticUpdate;
    private String updateApiToken;
    private Boolean latestVersion;

}
```

Basically I would be interested in a solution, but a good report or even just a suggestion would be enough for me :).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just create an object, for example: ConfigData, then create and CRUD endpoints for that?

Comment: Yes, that was also my first thought. But can I make entities out of my configuration files?

Comment: Sure, you can use Properties class to read and write your own file.

Answer (score 0):

> I have created 2 config files. I can already use the parameters in the
> application.properties. My goal is to be able to display and edit the
> parameters later in the frontend. Like normal settings of any
> application.

I will add my notice here, because the question of how to pass them to UI may be valid but the outcome may be wrong for you.

In a Spring Boot application, the properties that you use and load via `@Configuration`
`@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.general")` are loaded only during spring context initialization which happens when the application starts up. So considering that those properties already exist in your `application.properties` file, your Frontend would not be able to persist the changed properties somewhere.

1 Possible scenario I see for this requirement, is that those properties are loaded from Database and not `application.properties`, and then when edited the database records are edited to be persistent. Then you have to either restart the application or try to manually refresh the spring context for those properties to take effect. For this solution you could just create an endpoint from your `spring-boot` application that delivers all properties that exist in database and then another endpoint to edit those properties. Like simple crud operations.

2 Possible scenario but may be a bit overkill is to use `cloud config server`. Search for `spring cloud bus` and `spring actuator refresh` to see how you can apply some out of the box solutions for an application that needs dynamic properties.